# Problem while using Calva / Reveal together

Tags: clojure, nrepl, vscode-calva

I was using Vscode + Calva for developing Clojure.
And I watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIoadGfm5T8&t=2392s) and try to use Reveal with Calva.

I see [this](https://calva.io/reveal/) and add **cider.nrepl/cider-middleware** to middleware.

(I'm using [this](https://github.com/practicalli/clojure-deps-edn) `deps.edn` and just add `cider/cider-nrepl {:mvn/version "0.26.0"}` and `cider.nrepl/cider-middleware`. doc mentioned only `cider.nrepl/cider-middleware`, but in my environment, without `cider/cider-nrepl {:mvn/version "0.26.0"}` makes error. it saids no cider in classpath)

Here's my deps.edn.

```
:repl/reveal-light-nrepl
  {:extra-deps {vlaaad/reveal     {:mvn/version "1.3.212"}
                nrepl/nrepl       {:mvn/version "0.8.3"}
                cider/cider-nrepl {:mvn/version "0.26.0"}}
   :jvm-opts   ["-Dvlaaad.reveal.prefs={:theme,:light,:font-family,\"https://ff.static.1001fonts.net/u/b/ubuntu.mono.ttf\",:font-size,32}"]
   :main-opts  ["-m" "nrepl.cmdline"
                "--middleware" "[vlaaad.reveal.nrepl/middleware, cider.nrepl/cider-middleware]"]}
```

When I run `clojure -M:repl/reveal-light-nrepl`, Reveal works fine.

Now I want to use it with my project with Calva.

I mean, `clojure -M:repl/reveal-light-nrepl` is just standalone. not project integrated.

What should I do?

I think line in [this](https://calva.io/reveal/) might help.

```
And then jack-in choosing the deps.edn option and then pick the :reveal-nrepl-middleware alias.
```

But I don't know what it means. (I'm a Clojure newbie.)
I know how to jack-in. But what I see is just choosing build option. I don't see reveal-nrepl-middleware.

Maybe I should look at Custom REPL Connect Sequences?

Comment: Can you provide us with the error message you’re receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Following the [link](https://calva.io/reveal/) that you provided, I would try this:

> Dependencies only
>
> If you don't want to use the nrepl-middleware you can configure just the dependency and then start Reveal yours
>
> The alias:

```
:reveal-dep-only {:extra-deps {vlaaad/reveal {:mvn/version "1.3.194"}}}
```

> A custom REPL command for starting Reveal in your project:

```
    "calva.customREPLCommandSnippets": [
    ...
    {
        "name": "Start Reveal Tapper",
        "snippet": "(require '[vlaaad.reveal :as reveal])(add-tap (reveal/ui))",
        "key": "sr"
    },
    ...
]
```

> See [Custom REPL Command](https://calva.io/custom-commands/) for how to configure more commands, and bind shortcuts to them, to make Reveal integration nice for you.

Messing with the middleware options can be a bit tricky for a beginner, so I would try to steer clear from that.  If you just add the deps then you can include `:reveal-dep-only` from the alias drop down when you jack-in via Calva.  Then, once in the REPL window, fire off the custom command snippet using the "key" that you defined in your `settings.json`

Another option that I would like to point out is [Portal](https://github.com/djblue/portal).  Portal is browser based, and works by registering a `tap>`, which is my preferred way to debug these days.

There's even a Portal extension for vscode which handles all the integration for you!
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=djblue.portal